# SwiftUI : Binding the sum of @State value

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, slider

I tried to compute the sum of three numbers using sliders and any change in sliders number will automatically change the value on the computed value slider. I add some issues with the sum of the binding numbers. Maybe I missed a property.
I am just staring with Swift

Any solution for this?

Many Thanks

Fred

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var number1 = 0
@State private var number2 = 0
@State private var number3 = 0
@State private var computedValue = 0


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
         Text("Number 1")
             Picker("Number 1", selection: $number1, content: {
                 Text("0").tag(0)
                 Text("1").tag(1)
                 Text("2").tag(2)
                 Text("3").tag(3)
             }
             ).pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            Text("Number 2")
                Picker("Number 2", selection: $number2, content: {
                    Text("0").tag(0)
                    Text("1").tag(1)
                    Text("2").tag(2)
                    Text("3").tag(3)
                }
                ).pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            Text("Number 3")
                Picker("Number 3", selection: $number3, content: {
                    Text("0").tag(0)
                    Text("1").tag(1)
                    Text("2").tag(2)
                    Text("3").tag(3)
                }
                ).pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            Text("Computed value")
           
            Picker("computed", selection: sum(n1: number1, n2: number2, n3: number3) , content: {
                Text("0").tag(0)
                Text("1").tag(1)
                Text("2").tag(2)
                Text("3").tag(3)
                Text("4").tag(4)
                Text("5").tag(5)
                Text("6").tag(6)
                Text("7").tag(7)
                Text("8").tag(8)
                Text("9").tag(9)


            }
            ).pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

func sum (n1: Int, n2: Int, n3: Int) -> Int {
    
    return n1 + n2 + n3
}
```

Comment: Binding is used to update the value. What does it mean to update the computed sum? If sum is just another independent property that was at one point equal to the actual sum, then as soon as you update it, it is no longer the actual sum. So what is the behavior that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.constant`

```
Picker("computed", selection: Binding.constant(sum(n1: number1, n2: number2, n3: number3)) , content: { // < - Here
```